# Why stack frame aligned by 24 bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am reading *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 3rd Edition* by Randal E. Bryant and David R. O'Hallaron.

In chapter 3 and section 7.5, there is figure demonstrating how stack frames are allocated as follows:

[image: figure]

I couldn't understand that why are line 4 and 12 needed. It seems that those lines are not required because the surplus 8 bytes of stack memory are not used at all.

As comment indicates, IMHO, it seems that it is inevitably allocated to align stack frame by 24 bytes:

- additional 16 bytes for `pushq %rbp` and `pushq %rbx` respectively
- , and 8 bytes for `subq $8, %rsp`

So, my question can be summarized to "*Why stack frames are aligned by 24 bytes?*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is consistent with x64 ABI (both Microsoft and SystemV). Stack must be aligned on 16 bytes boundary before calling a function ("call Q" in your example). Let's assume that the stack is initially at a 16 bytes boundary. When the program reaches "P" label (due to a "call P" instruction), RSP points 8 byte below, because "call" subtracts 8 to RSP and saves RIP (8 bytes) at *RSP. Then, there are two "pushq" (line 2 and 3), each decreases RSP by 8, so RSP is still misaligned. That's why The compiler must subtract 8 to align RSP before executing "call Q" at line 8 and 10.

This article describes x86/x64 ABIs quite well:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 7):

24 bytes is not a power of 2 and hence cannot be an alignment.  The real alignment is to 16 bytes and you forgot to account for the `call` instruction also pushing 8 bytes on the stack.  So in total, the stack pointer is moved by 32 bytes, preserving alignment to 16 bytes.

Comment: Why should there be a requirement that alignments are a power of 2? In most cases it might not make much sense; however, a calling convention that requires an 48-byte alignment (maybe because of some operating system requirements) would definitely be possible.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: How would you efficiently achieve `rsp % 48 == 0`?  Just not plausible on a binary computer.  The standard concept of alignment is some amount of low bits in the address being zero, and thus not crossing any wider boundary.  Just like for ISO C++ `alignof()`, we only ever talk about power of 2 alignments on x86.  Maintaining `rsp % 48 == 0` would be something you *could* do via dead-reckoning I guess (with extra expense for VLAs to make sure you were moving RSP by a multiple of 48), but we wouldn't call it an alignment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Surely, normally it is not plausible. But I could imagine some weird graphics hardware that multiplies a register value by 3 to access a triple of (R,G,B) bytes using the DMA. In this case, a variable holding pixel values must be located at a 3-aligned address. An operating system for a machine using an x64 CPU and such a strange hardware would probably use a calling convention with a 48-byte stack alignment to ensure that local variables are both 16-byte aligned (for SSE operations) and 3-byte aligned (for the graphics DMA).